# Why would spWeb.Site.RootWeb.AssociatedOwnerGroup be null?

Tags: groups

We have code that does the following:

1. Creates a new `SPWeb` programmatically within a site collection.
2. Adds a new `SPGroup` to the programmatically-created `SPWeb` using `spWeb.SiteGroups.Add(string name, SPMember owner, SPUser defaultUser, string description)`.

The invocation to add the SPGroup looks like this:

```
spWeb.SiteGroups.Add("Group Name", spWeb.Site.RootWeb.AssociatedOwnerGroup,
    spWeb.CurrentUser, "Group Description");
```

On all of our environments except for 1, this code works as expected. The `owner` of the new `SPGroup` is set to the `AssociatedOwnerGroup` of the site collection's root web.

However on one of our environments, `spWeb.Site.RootWeb.AssociatedOwnerGroup` is null, and thus the call to `spWeb.SiteGroups.Add` throws an `ArgumentNullException` for the `owner` argument.

We have checked, and the root site collection's `Owners` group is there.

What would cause `spWeb.Site.RootWeb.AssociatedOwnerGroup` to return null?

Notes:

The `spWeb.CurrentUser` is a site collection administrator.

We have tried wrapping this in `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why it could be empty - perhaps was deleted at some point (this has happened to me before). You can set the owner by visiting _layouts/permsetup.aspx of your site collection.

Comment: Yes, that did it. Never heard of this ASPX before, is there any way to get to it without typing in the URL?

Comment: Great! I don't think there is a way to the page through the UI. The groups are also configurable through PowerShell. See [this page](http://weshackett.com/2011/01/creating-default-groups-with-powershell/)